# Angular cannot connect to Spring Boot Web Services in a kubernete cluster: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: angular, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it.
I have an angular apps.
One running on port 30003 called issuer web services on port 30001.

I have a spring boot web services.
One called "issuer web services" is running on port "30001".

I am running both apps using "minikube".
The Angular app seemed to have problem connecting to the web services.
The Angular app "issuer" cannot connect to web services 30001.

Here is my workloads.yaml:

```
            apiVersion: apps/v1
        kind: Deployment
        metadata:
          name: issuerwebservices
        spec:
          selector:
            matchLabels:
              app: issuerwebservices
          replicas: 1
          template: # template for the pods
            metadata:
              labels:
            app: issuerwebservices
            spec:
              containers:
               - name: issuerwebservices
             image: jadeite1000/issuerwebservices:latest
             ports:
             - containerPort: 30001
```

Here is my services.yaml:

```
            ---
        apiVersion: v1
        kind: Service
        metadata:
          name: issuerwebservices

        spec:
          # This defines which pods are going to be represented by this Service
          # The service becomes a network endpoint for either other services
          # or maybe external users to connect to (eg browser)
          selector:
            app: issuerwebservices

          ports:
            - name: http
              port: 30001
              targetPort: 30001
              nodePort: 30001
              protocol: TCP

          type: NodePort
```

In the Angular environment.prod.ts:

```
        export const environment = {
      production: false,

      baseUrl: 'http://issuerwebservices:30001/'
    };
```

Here is the error I get in the console:

[image]

Comment: I don't see any ports listed in your `Deployment`s. See examples [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) that include `containerPort`. You typically need a [`Service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) as well.

Comment: Hi blacktide, sorry I copy the wrong text. I now updated services.yaml file.

Comment: The only thing that it appears you are missing is the `.spec.template.spec.containers[0].ports[0].containerPort` field in your `Deployment` manifests. See the highlighted portion of [this image](https://i.imgur.com/w0BMHbG.png).

Comment: Hi blacktid, I am not clear What is Deployment manifests? I have post my services.yaml. In apiVersion: v1

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 30003
      protocol: TCP
  type: NodePort

Comment: In your post, in the `workloads.yaml` section, you have 4 `Deployment`s. Those need to define the port, under the `image`. Check the screenshot I linked for an example (the part you need is highlighted).

Comment: Hi blacktide, first I want to thank you so much for helping me!! I updated the workload.yaml file for adding "containerPort" for each pod. But I still cannot connect from the Angular application to the web services application.

Comment: Hi blacktide, I updated the workloads.yaml based your recommendation. However, I am still getting same connection error from Angular to Web Services.